# Sockets Programming with Python: Get the port of a server

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tkinter

So as the title suggests is there any way that I can get the port of a website/ip with a socket connection? I assigned `socket.gethostbyname()` to the simple variable "ip" so that I can print out the result in console but can I do the same with the port? Here is the website that I am using to learn with > https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html < and what I am wondering is if this is a good source or does anyone know a better one? Thank you much :D

Comment: It is common to use predefined port numbers. The standard ones can be looked up (example, http is port 80)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can get the currently used port with `getsockname`:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 0))
print('listening on port:', sock.getsockname()[1])
```